# When I use MatDialog, ngOnInit only fire the first time. Why?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I got some datas from Firebase and I use them in a Component called Categories that I open in a dialog box with MatDialog.

When I open the dialog for the first time, I got my datas and they are displayed. But when **I close the dialog and reopen it**, the datas disappear.

I subscribe the datas in ngOnInit.

**add-event.component.ts**

```js
    export class AddEventComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }

      openDialog() {

            const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CategoriesComponent, {
                height: '400px',
                width: '600px',
            });

            dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
                console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`); // Pizza!
            });



        }

    }
```

**categories.component.ts**

```js
    export class CategoriesComponent implements OnInit {

        categories: Category[];

        constructor(private categoryService: CategoryService) {
        }

        ngOnInit() {

            this.categoryService.getCategories().subscribe(categories => {
                console.log(categories);
                this.categories = categories;
            });
        }
    }
```

**categories.component.html**

```html
    <h2 mat-dialog-title>Delete all</h2>
    <mat-dialog-content>


      <div *ngIf="categories?.length >0; else noCategories">
        <ul *ngFor="let category of categories" class="collection">
          <li (dblclick)="deleteCategory($event, category)" class="collection-item">
            <b>{{category.name}}</b> : {{category.color}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <ng-template #noCategories>
        <hr>
        <h5>No Categories</h5>
      </ng-template>

    </mat-dialog-content>
    <mat-dialog-actions>
      <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>No</button>
      <!-- The mat-dialog-close directive optionally accepts a value as a result for the dialog. -->
      <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true">Yes</button>
    </mat-dialog-actions>
```

Is something that I'm doing wrong? Do I need to pass the data through the Dialog (this solution seems not clean...) ?

Thanks !

Comment: It seems that it's not a problem with ngOnInit(). It works but not the subscription.

Comment: Everything looks okay,try `console.log('test')` in ngOnInit method before subscribing to debug.
It should log two times.
The Problem might be in service.Can you share the code?

Comment: I put the code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service might not be singleton, so just shift the code to `getCategories()` like so

```
getCategories() {
   this.categoriesCollection = this.afs.collection('categories', ref => 
    ref.orderBy('name', 'asc'));

        return this.categoriesCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes => {
              return changes.map(a => {
                  const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Category; // To get the id form Firestore
                  data.id = a.payload.doc.id; 
                  return data;
              });
          }));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the service :

```
    categoriesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Category>;
    categories: Observable<Category[]>;

    constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
          this.categoriesCollection = this.afs.collection('categories', ref => ref.orderBy('name', 'asc'));

          this.categories = this.categoriesCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes => {
              return changes.map(a => {
                  const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Category; // To get the id form Firestore
                  data.id = a.payload.doc.id; 
                  return data;
              });
          }));
      }

    getCategories() {
        return this.categories;
    }
```

And if I debug with console.log in ngOnInit, it fires all the time. So, It's a problem with the Subscription.